Call for testers for an early access release of a Stack Overflow extension for GitHub Copilot
Today on Labs, we announced an upcoming limited release for a Stack Overflow extension that we are working on for GitHub Copilot. We had previously previewed this at WeAreDevelopers in July.
Similarly to how we initially launched the Beta for Staging Ground and other Alpha features through Stack Overflow Labs, we’d like people who are interested in testing and providing feedback to let us know.  We’re opening the early access release to a limited number of users. Once you’re admitted, you’ll receive an invite to a Stack Overflow for Teams instance that you will need to accept to gain access to the extension. We’ll use the Team area as a place for testers to report bugs, provide feedback, etc. We’ll be starting with a small number of testers and then increasing from there in the near future. After the limited release, we plan on eventually deprecating the Teams-based access and allowing general access to the Stack Overflow extension.
This is an opportunity to help inform and shape the direction of the Stack Overflow extension for GitHub Copilot. If you are interested in participating and providing feedback, please sign up here.

Will the answers provided by the extension give credit to the real content producers?

Does the LLM have a large blue banner at the top of every response it gives that states "Reminder: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow. Learn more"? If not, consider that a [[meta-tag:feature-request]].

@AugustoVasques I answered your question below and included a screen shot.

@ThomA why do we need that?! If anything this is better than many other LLM tools, "answering" without any attribution. We have that banner here on SO, I don't understand where that banner fits within VSCode for an extension. Don't get me wrong, I am not for AI in no shape or form, but I'd rather be fair than criticizing every move the company makes to secure some funds. That said, adding a warning such as that to the extension when installing it doesn't sound like an entirely bad idea.

Is this specific to a certain IDE?

I just have zero confidence that there will be no users that will copy the content from the LLM to an answer here on [so], @M-- .

@ThomA I understand your reservations, but I just don't see a place (besides a warning when installing) for that banner within an IDE.

More intellectual theft from humans to companies using AI. Attribution is not payment.  The permanent white collar recAIssion continues to grow from this fuel.

SO ignores any feedback that isn't 100% in agreement so I don't see how this will be any different. Maybe try fiverr or hiring some additional QA.

There is some really crappy code on github, how does this black-magic discriminate between good and bad?

@DavidC.Rankin judging by previous attempts it'll hallucinate something even worse :v

GitHub Copilot is a paid service.  Is this only open to paid subscribers?  Or are you going to provide the paid service for free to your free testers?

@mdfst13 I asked in the SOfT on October 30th and have not gotten any response, which I find mildly disappointing in terms of how SO Inc engages with people who volunteer their time, but... what else is new

What about voting?

Are the co-pilot answers somehow actually "better" with this "extension" or is this more like a way to drive search clicks back to the main site?

What about rewards? Should we leave? I am sure someone in there could build websites, maybe he should, it's time.

Can we opt out of having our answers used by the LLM?  I agreed to have my answers hosted on Stack, not used by this.

@Tarazed related: https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service, and https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/

@starball That's fine, I'll just go delete all my answer history then.

@Tarazed before you attempt that, I suggest you read https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/399769/997587

This is in response to Augusto Vasques' question in the comments around attribution. Answers will include a list of sources that link back to SO posts and name their authors.
I'm including a screenshot of what it will look like. The person asking has been greyed out, but the author names are displayed.


Do you - as in, the company - believe that this meets all of the attribution requirements of the CC BY-SA license? I'm not entirely convinced that it does, but it may also depend on how much of the output consists of the words of these individuals versus a summary.

@ThomasOwens - I question if proper attribution has been given, that summary seems to have summarized multiple answers together potentially, making attribution difficult to make clear. It would be interesting what I more substantial code response would look like,

How does the attribution code work internally? If it's an entirely separate AI that takes the unattributed text and spits out some links, there is no telling if those links will be at all relevant.

@SecurityHound That's what I'm getting at. If it is truly a summary and doesn't contain the authors' words, this could be sufficient. But if it includes enough of someone's licensed content, It doesn't meet the required criteria. Perhaps there's also an argument that the information is available by clicking through and that is "reasonable to medium, means, and context".

@ThomasOwens it's going to depend. sometimes it'll be a summary like this, other times it'll be a large code snippet that is 1:1 with exactly 1 of the answers and not the rest plus aigen text above it. (see their recent video on Overflow AI)

@KevinB I'll have to watch the video. Not sure if I saw one or fully appreciated it. But if is taking large chunks of multiple answers, then I would expect clear attribution of which pieces come from which answers. But if it's a summary, then I would expect citation than attribution.

@ThomasOwens it was this one https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=3CUrM_lUIZM though it’s still probably impossible to know just from looking at the results if it’s a summary or a fully aigen answer with linked “related” questions.

This could be improved, but it's a lot better than the nameless attribution in the previous blog post. Thanks for the progress!

I was initially apprehensive but this actually looks halfway decent from an attribution perspective. Will there be any way for CoPilot users to then provide feedback to the answerers (and by that I mean, votes? Or at least the "anonymous feedback" votes?)

Do the links to the answers link to a specific revision or just to the answer on the live page? I think it's critical they link to a specific revision. Also, it would be good to show the title of the question after the answer link. Doesn't have to be a link itself, but knowing what question (or questions) the real human-written answers addressed would be just as useful as an AI tool at helping the user learn for themselves (e.g., "Oh, the answers used here were to questions titled "XYZ", but I only thought to ask "ABC". Now I know how to search better next time!")

Will hovering over a specific source answer in the source section highlight the parts of the AI answer that were based on said source answer? If not, can that please be added?

Tried to find which ones those answers could be, Mike West
VonC
VonC
(He has a lot, and he also point to Community Wiki)
1/2

John Szakmeister
manojlds 2/2

@TylerH: Agreed about question titles missing.  With titles, an interesting one could catch your attention and make you realize there was an aspect of your problem you hadn't even thought to ask about.  Or just that it looks interesting, and lead you to the SO post where you might vote or comment and interact with the person who's answer you've benefited from.  With just author names, it seems a lot less likely that someone would bother to click any of the links unless they make a point of upvoting answers that helped them, and more likely to suck life out of the community.

I see "thumbs up" and "thumbs down" there. What do they do?
I see it as a problem, if no more green internet points are awarded, because people get the same helpful answer, but regurgitated by an AI instead of viewed through the interface that also gives access to the buttons for voting.
I would also see it as a problem if it did work like mass-voting and there would be downvotes on posts, because the mix of the specific answer with all other answers on the topic is not helpful. Yeah. I mean that is why there are multiple distinct answers, right?
So either way, I see problems. How are you addressing those?

I have strong feelings such extension is a first step to kill SO. Though maybe SO and similar sites will die anywhere in the future due to copilot/assistant/whatever. GitHub seems to be safe (as its main role is repository).

@nvoigt The thumbs up/down is from Copilot itself and has no impact on the posts or their scores. There’s no voting through the extension in this version and we want to learn more about how people use it before exploring how to incorporate voting. As you mentioned, there are risks that posts get rewarded or penalized unfairly. For now, we think the sources will direct people on-site where they can vote (assuming they have that privilege). Please let us know if you have ideas to propose.

Engagement on SO is already down considerably during the past 4-5 years, this would seem to accelerate that trend. Who needs a community when a bot work work?

You need the community to feed the bots. In fact, you need a large community to feed them decently. Kill the community, no more bots, or, rather, bots hallucinating wildly, which is not exactly 'helpful'. So, no, I don't think that the ultimate goal is to destroy whole communities in a misguided belief that the extra cash will compensate it somehow.

LLM's will commonly have a thumbs up or down on their responses for feedback, from what I have observed. It doesn't look to be related to Stack Overflow itself, aside from perhaps the quality of its generation.

@GwynethLlewelyn "I don't think that the ultimate goal is to destroy whole communities in a misguided belief that the extra cash will compensate it" - Never underestimate stupidity.

@Starship-OnDiscussionsStrike I stand corrected. I forgot to take Cipolla's basic laws of human stupidity in account, namely, #1 — "Always and inevitably, everyone underestimates the number of stupid individuals in circulation." Stupidity is universal across all strata of society; it's not a privilege of the poor and illiterate. sigh

Could you please add a reminder to the extension somewhere that posting AI generated content on SO is not allowed? I imagine some users may think they are helpful and then post the AI’s answer (still).

that already exists in the answer box.

Unless and until you dismiss it once, then it's gone forever. Also, it's gone as soon as you type/paste something into the answer box. I think there's room for improvement here. But it's not really related to this specific announcement. Unless you're talking about adding that reminder to the GitHub Copilot extension?

@CodyGray adding it to the extension what I meant, yes

There doesn't seem to be a way to post answers (or questions) through this IDE extension to the website, so I don't see how this is relevant. Do you really think someone will go to the linked question and post the AI-generated summary of the other answers?

@Bergi Honestly, yes.

@Bergi Oh yes, for sure.
